# How to solve "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'SpeedTest.Program.SpeedLimit'"

Tags: c#, enums

Create an application that will request the user to enter the zone they are traveling within and their current driving speed. Use validation to ensure only one of the correct zones is entered.

Create an enumeration to hold the zone names and a 2nd enumeration to hold the speed limit of each zone.

If the driver’s speed exceeds the speed limit in the current zone traveled, display an appropriate message reminding them of the speed limit else thank the driver for keeping within the specified zone speed limit.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SpeedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        enum ZoneName
        {
            SCHOOL = 1, CITY, HIGHWAY
        }
        enum SpeedLimit
        {
            SCHOOL_ZONE_SPEED = 20,
            CITY_STREET_SPEED = 30,
            HIGHWAY_SPEED = 55
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ZoneName zone;
            SpeedLimit sl;
            int iZone;

            System.Console.WriteLine("*********************************");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a zone number");
            System.Console.WriteLine("1.School");
            System.Console.WriteLine("2.City");
            System.Console.WriteLine("3.Highway");
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("*********************************");

            iZone = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());

            System.Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your current speed");
            int currentSpeed = Convert.ToInt16(System.Console.ReadLine());

            zone = (ZoneName)iZone;

            switch (zone)
            {
                case ZoneName.SCHOOL:
                    if (currentSpeed > SpeedLimit.SCHOOL_ZONE_SPEED)//i have errors by my if statements 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Slow down and maintain the speed limit of 20 ine the School Zone");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for maintaining the speed limit in the School Zone ");
                    }
                    break;
                case ZoneName.CITY:
                    if (currentSpeed > SpeedLimit.CITY_STREET_SPEED)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Slow down and maintain the speed limit of 30 in the City Zone");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for maintaining the speed limit in the City Zone ");
                    }
                    break;
                case ZoneName.HIGHWAY:
                    if (currentSpeed > SpeedLimit.HIGHWAY_SPEED)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Slow down and maintain the speed limit of 55 on the Highway Zone");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for maintaining the speed limit in the Highway Zone ");
                    }
                    break;

                    System.Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
···
```

Comment: `SpeedLimit` is a really strange usage of an `enum` to bundle constants together.  I think that'd be better defined as separate `const int`s — which would eliminate the whole `>` operator issue — or a `Dictionary<ZoneName, int>`.  I see that's explicitly called for in the text of the assignment; hopefully the author isn't teaching you any similar (mis)uses of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `SpeedLimit` enum as integer before comparing the values.

```cs
if (currentSpeed > (int)SpeedLimit.SCHOOL_ZONE_SPEED)
```